# Sharing folder for Network drive

Tags: networking, network-shares, windows-server-2008

I have 3 computers, A - B - C, all connected locally. (I am physically using computer A)

I've remoted on computer B, and shared a folder with full access to `Everyone` and `Anonymous Logon`.
Then, I remoted onto computer C, and mapped a Network Drive `Z` to the shared folder on B.

The issue comes in when other people remote onto computer C, but they can't see the `Z` drive. I have logged off and back on with my account, and can always see the remote drive.
I have services running on computer C that relies on the content in the shared drive, but it seems that those services can't see the content either...

I have tried moving ownership of the `Z` drive to the Administrator of Computer C, as well as grant access to everything as best as I could.

A - Windows 8
B / C - Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

All mapped drives are user specific not computer specific.

What you need to configure is a way of mapping the Z drive upon log in so all users get the drive mapped when they remote on/log on.

You can use either log in script which can be placed within the log in folder:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Create a file in notepad to say

```
Net use Z: \\computerb\sharename
```

`Save as > Filename.vbs`

and place in

```
 C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Or if you are on a domain you can create a group policy to map the drive on log in.. I wont go through instructions for this unless you feel this is the correct route for you in which case please let me know.

Comment: I won't be able to run a startup script - mainly because I can't restart the PC. We are on a domain though.

Comment: That's fine it doesn't require a restart. If you was to place a startup script in that folder it should take affect on next login...

Comment: Actually scrap that its Server 2008 I'm being an idiot thinking its a workstation OS. Go to Windows\system32\ within here you should find a file called USRLOGON.CMD which runs every time a user logs on. You could add the net user command in here to take affect at logon.